# What is set option query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

My database has currently a lot of queries, the most of them should be "INSERT", but I am having a "set option" command almost 5 times more (almost 5 millions per hour!).

[image]

What is "set option"?, should I avoid it?

Comment: most likely your code at the time of creating database connection would have been calling `set sql_mode = ''`. `set` is use to set variables, which can be global, system, session variables etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is SET OPTION command.

[Mysql SET documentation][1]
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-variable.html

OFF TOPIC
It is a lot of connections. You should try to use connection pooling. It can speedup your app.